# Collapse item up in bootstrap 4

Tags: bootstrap-4

Is there a way to collapse items up in bootstrap 4? As in to change the direction of collapse. Rather than having the default behaviour of collapsing the element below the trigger, i would like it to collapse the element above. Just like we have for dropup

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways, for an item to align it left or right, you can user `style = 'float: right/left;'` and if you want a set of items to another side you can lay it out via `row` and `col` class names.

Comment: I'm not talking about alignment. I mean when using collapse, it normally acts like a drop down. It shows the collapsed elements below the anchor once you click on the anchor. But I want it to act in a reverse way by showing the collapsed element above the anchor. Just like we have in dropdown and dropup